# is it possible change the source of the page with selenium (phpunit)?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

In my site I have a refresher ( function that update table's data from time to time )
I try to stop it when I do my tests.the easiest way to stop this function is to overwrite it. 
for this I need one of two, write:

`function refresher(){}` into the `console.log` or just inject `<script>function refresher(){}</script>`

my question: how can I write into page source with selenium ?

thanks.

EDIT:
to make it works with phpunit-selenium:

```
$script = file_get_contents( "script.js" );
$this->execute( array(
         'script' => $script,
         'args'  => array()
));
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do this? How about just removing the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, using [JavascriptExecutor](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html). Like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("read js from file");
```

And your js content should be like this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text  = "function refresher(){}" 
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This will do what you need. But just think over, why you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to overwrite your function would be like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.refresher = function () {};");
```

Using `window.refresher` rather than `refresher` makes it clear that your intent is to overwrite the global `refresher` function.